# DROP command denied to user X for table 'Y'

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

We are getting ready for a big SQL migration.

Currently, I have the code written, and I am testing it out with data on my local machine.

Step 1 is to throw out the existing data in the table before I import the new stuff:

```
using (var txn = m_mySqlConnection.BeginTransaction()) {
    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE `blah_blah`;", m_mySqlConnection, txn)) {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    // other code
}
```

But, the `TRUNCATE` command is throwing an exception whenever I try to execute it with the MySQL user account I am running the code with:

[image: code screenshot]

I tried going into MySQL Workbench to give this userid `DROP` permission, but all I could find was a way to add `DROP` under the **View** section.

I tried that, but it did not work.

[image: workbench screenshot]

How do I go about giving this user the ability to remove the data in these tables so that I can test my populate script?

Comment: try `DELETE FROM Table`

Comment: That worked, Daniel. I did a search before writing my code, and what I found was to use `TRUNCATE` instead of `DELETE`. I don't know why. Delete seems to do fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TRUNCATE` deletes the table. Try using `DELETE FROM Table`.